# Render datatable row in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, datatable, datatables

I'm getting the data in response but can't add it the datatable row. Can anyone please help me out with this?

This is what I'm trying to do:

`````
    export default (id) => {

  if (!$.fn.dataTable) return;

  $('#'+id).DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    pageLength: 8,
    responsive: true,
    ordering: false,
    searching: false,
    info: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    stripeClasses: [],
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      url  : `${Config.baseUrl}/homepark/list?page_no=1&settingType=dashboard&isActive=1&categoryId=active-listings`,
      type : 'GET',
      "beforeSend" : function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('userToken',localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));
      },
      "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
        const data = json.response.users
        console.log('@@@', data);
        // data = data.row\````
      },
    },
  });
};
`````

This is what I'm getting as a result from backend in `json.response.users`:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "testt", data: "0"}
1: {name: "testt11", data: "1"}
2: {name: "testt11", data: "2"}
3: {name: "testt11", data: "3"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's two problems there - this example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html) shows how to solve both.

your data isn't under a "data" object, it's at the top level, so you want to set ajax.dataSrc to "" (see example).
as you're returning an array of objects, you need to tell DataTables how the columns match to the object's elements. See columns.data as in that example,